# Database Migration in TYPO3

Tags: php, typo3, database-migration, typo3-extensions, typo3-9.x

I've started to refactor the ext:crawler to make it compatible with TYPO3 9LTS.

Currently we have a domain model based only on a database table + a TCA configuration:

https://github.com/AOEpeople/crawler/blob/master/ext_tables.sql#L48
https://github.com/AOEpeople/crawler/blob/master/Configuration/TCA/tx_crawler_configuration.php

I want to add a regular Domain Model and Repository for the Configurations instead, to benefit more from the code from TYPO3 Core.

My problem is currently:

I don't know how to migrate data from the already existing table `tx_crawler_configuration` to the new `tx_crawler_domain_model_configuration` without the users are loosing any data, or need to do any manual work.

I haven't found anything on this topic yet. I know I can "use foreign data source" but it's not foreign data, so not sure this is the best approach.
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/4-use-foreign-data-sources.html

I appreciate your input, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Torben Hansen just did something similar, when he migrated `sf_bannners` from using own Category concept to use the sys_category concept of TYPO3

What he does is creating a ext_update.php script that is being called automatically upon installation. You can see his commit here

https://github.com/derhansen/sf_banners/commit/02c2c6f1729b96940bb4dd0ca29761fe48d28c14

and probably catch him on Slack with any questions

Comment: Thanks will look into this.. Looks like at least a step in the right direction.

Comment: For other visitors of this question: There have been some changes in the TYPO3 API and class.ext_update.php is discouraged. For TYPO3 9 and beyond, please see Changelog or section in "TYPO3 Explained": https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/UpdateWizards/ExtUpdateFile.html